# как синхронизировать websocket и nfc

Tags: node.js, websocket, nfc

Я с помощью nodejs читаю данные с nfc карты(использую библиотеку nfc-pcsc). У меня есть проблема. Я точно могу узнать когда у меня происходить подключение или отключение nfc устройства, и могу знать подключен или отключен ли websocket. Как сделать так что бы я могу синхронизировать подключение websocket(клиент - сервер) и подключение nfc устройства? Проблема в том что nfc работает вот так: `nfc.on('reader', reader => {});` ну и websocket: `wsServer.on('connection', onConnect);`. Мне необходимо что бы сначала подключился websocket, а потом уже отрабатывал nfc.

Comment: сервер что-то шлёт на клиента или просто получает данные?

Comment: И шлет и получает